Why is the phenyl shift happening?
In the mechanism here, why is the phenyl shift happening instead of O from OH attacking the +ve carbon? also both the carbons are 3 degree...so what is the need of shift ?


It does, but the resulting epoxide then protonates giving an equivalent intermediate cation and ultimately the phenyl shift occurs giving the same product so it is simpler to express the mechanism this way

And even if the hydroxyl shifted without epoxide formation, you would form the same cation, an event that gets you nowhere.

The need for shift is the much greater stability of the back bond stabilized cation formed on phenyl shift. Also Phenyl's migratory aptitude is greater than methyl due to higher electron density, and when the carbocation is getting back bond stabilized, in these type of cases, the migratory aptitude is strictly followed.
So phenyl shift is happening here.
